# Pinescript - Prevent Labels from Overlapping

Tags: label, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to create a study that will plot multiple MAs on a single chart and label them. The issue is that the labels will sometime overlap. My actual pine script is a lot more complex than this, but I'm trying to fix this on a barebones case so I can scale it up to my actual script. Here is the code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Example", overlay=true)

// Study 1
ma1 = ta.sma(close, 5)

// Study 2
ma2 = ta.sma(close, 7)

// Study 3
ma3 = ta.sma(close, 9)

// Plot Studies
plot(ma1, color = color.green, linewidth=2, title='Moving Average 1')
plot(ma2, color = color.blue, linewidth=2, title='Moving Average 2')
plot(ma3, color = color.red, linewidth=2, title='Moving Average 3')

// Declare labels in global scope
label curlabel = na
label prevlabel = na
label label1 = na
label label2 = na
label label3 = na

// Prevent label overlap
if barstate.islast
    // Set the initial label locations to their MAs
    label1 := label.new(bar_index+3, ma1, "5 SMA", color=color.green, style = label.style_label_left)
    label2 := label.new(bar_index+3, ma2, "7 SMA", color=color.blue, style = label.style_label_left)
    label3 := label.new(bar_index+3, ma3, "9 SMA", color=color.red, style = label.style_label_left)

    // Check if they overlap and adjust their y coordinates
    var labelArray = array.from(label1, label2, label3)
    for i = 0 to (array.size(labelArray) == 0 ? na : array.size(labelArray) - 1)
        curlabel := array.get(labelArray, i+1)
        prevlabel := array.get(labelArray, i)
        if not na(curlabel) and not na(prevlabel)
            if label.get_y(curlabel) >= label.get_y(prevlabel) - label.get_y(curlabel) - 25
                label.set_y(curlabel, label.get_y(prevlabel) - label.get_y(curlabel) - 25)
        array.push(labelArray, curlabel)
        
    // Delete previous instances of the label to prevent duplicate labels
    label.delete(label1[1])
    label.delete(label3[1])
    label.delete(label2[1])
```

What I've tried so far is to load the labels into an array, and then loop through the array to check the current label y location vs the prior label y location, and then adjust the current label y location.

For some reason this code needs more than 1 bar to print to even show all the labels, and even then it does not appear to be changing the y location at all.

If there is a better way to tackle this problem I'm all ears. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a ternary to change the position *y* of the label

```
lower_left  = ta.highest(high, 3)
upper_left  = ta.lowest(low, 3)
yLabel1     = ma1 > ma2 and ma1 > ma3 ? lower_left :
              ma1 > ma2 and ma1 < ma3 ? ma1 :
              ma1 < ma2 and ma1 < ma3 ? upper_left : na
```

And a ternary to change the *style* of the label

```
style1      = ma1 > ma2 and ma1 > ma3 ? label.style_label_lower_left :
              ma1 > ma2 and ma1 < ma3 ? label.style_label_left :
              ma1 < ma2 and ma1 < ma3 ? label.style_label_upper_left : na
```

Something like this:

```
label1 := label.new(bar_index+3, yLabel1, "5 SMA", color=color.green, style = style1)
```

[image]